# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!'

Tags: php, mysql

HI I'm trying to figure out how a piece o sample code works but when I try and run it I get the above error.
Kindly find line below

```
       if(!$_POST['user']    !$_POST['pass']){      //Affected Line 
         die('You did\'t fill in a required field.');   

   }
```

Thanks

Comment: `!$_POST['user']    !$_POST['pass']` And what kind of fancy condition should that be?

Answer (score 2):

You need a logical operator. I assume you want "or"

```
if(!$_POST['user'] || !$_POST['pass'])
```

I would personally check to see if they are empty:

```
if(empty($_POST['user']) || empty($_POST['pass']))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked almost wanted to ask why then after having a look it makes sense. Thanks again